# sqrt function gets error in racket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to build a simple function that gets a number, checks if the number is more the zero and return the square root of the number:

```
#lang pl 03

    (: sqrtt: Number -> Number)

    (define (sqrtt root)
      (cond [(null? root) error "no number ~s"]
            [( < root 0) error "`sqrt' requires a non-negative input ~s"]
            [else (sqrt root)]))
```

but the result I get when I'm trying to compile the function is:

> type declaration: too many types after identifier in: (: sqrtt: Number
>   -> Number)

Why am I getting that error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(define (sqrtt root)
  (cond [(null? root) (error "no number ~s")]
        [(< root 0)   (error "`sqrt' requires a non-negative input ~s")]
        [else (sqrt root)]))
```

You simply forgot the `()` around `error`. Remember that `error` is a procedure and, like all other procedures, to apply it you have to surround it with parentheses together with its arguments.

Comment: While it is true that he forgot parens around the `error`, that most certainly is not the cause of his problem. @Alex's answer is the cause of the problem.

(Although I'm not super familiar with the `pl` language, so that might also be the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting tells you that you have too many types after an identifier in a `:` type declaration. Now in racket, `sqrtt:` counts as an identifier. What you probably meant was `sqrtt :`, with a space in between.

```
(: sqrtt : Number -> Number)
```

The difference is that type declarations of the form `(: id : In ... -> Out)` are treated specially, but those of the form `(: id In ... -> Out)` are not. And `sqrtt:` is counts as the `id`.

There's also the problem Oscar Lopez pointed out, where you're missing parens around the `error` calls. Whenever you call a function in racket, including `error`, you need to wrap the function call in parens.

Also, the `(null? root)` clause is useless, since `root` has the type Number and `null?` will always return false for numbers.

And another thing, depending on what the `pl` language does, if you get a type error from `<` afterwards, that's because `<` operates on only Real numbers, but the Number type can include complex numbers. So you might have to change the type to `Real` or something.